# Can Linux take advantage of removable ram?

Tags: ram, removable-storage

Some RAM pci-e card were manufactured
https://linustechtips.com/topic/1118940-wtf-is-this-thing-ram-on-a-pci-card/

Say I got a removable 16gb version of this card that is available 95% of time (eg: down for 1 period of 15 minutes in 4 hours). Could Linux take advantage of this extra 16gb of PCI-RAM in a host that already have 16gb (non upgradable) ?
How much tweaking should be made to a typical installation?
Of course it won't go offline abruptly, a signal will be sent to the host.
The time and duration of interruption will be decided by user.

Solution 1:
As user expects the machine to be "paused" until the PCI-RAM is plugged again, I thought of going to hibernate mode. If the content of PCI-ram is preserved is it just a matter of going to hibernate mode, remove pci, replug pci, wake up ?

Solution 2:
Another solution would be to write all the content of ram to the local SSD before the PCI-RAM is removed. How could I achieve that ? Mount 2 swap partitions and give priority to the 16gb PCI swap ? And unmount/remount the swap when the pci is turned off/on ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as Gateway I-RAM cards (which is what Linus is discussing) go, they appear as SATA devices. Thus if you wanted to use them under Linux to help with RAM, you’d use them as a swap device, as suggested in your solution 2.

Removing one would then involve no longer using it as a swap device; that is doable at run time, you only need to ensure that either

- everything in swap fits in memory,
- or another swap device is available.

Swapping large amounts of data in or out is very slow by default under Linux unfortunately, but there are ways around that, *e.g.* using LVM and moving data from one physical volume (the RAM card) to another (its replacement storage).

Linux also supports hot-swappable storage devices, PCI devices, RAM, and even CPUs, on hot-swap-capable hardware (large servers). I-RAM cards are hybrid SATA/PCI devices — they use SATA for data transfer, and PCI for power. So assuming they support hot-swap SATA, on a hot-swap-capable PCI host you could stop using the card (as above), disconnect the SATA cable, power down the PCI slot, and remove the card.

On systems with hot-swappable memory, you need to inform the kernel that you wish to take a given memory device off-line (by writing to its `state` file in the appropriate `/sys/devices/system/memory` subdirectory); the kernel will then move all the pages on that memory device to another memory device, if possible, and once that’s done, the memory can be powered down and removed.

Trying to achieve something like this using hibernation is unlikely to work; systems don’t react too well to significant changes in hardware setup between the time they are put to sleep and they time they are woken up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does using LVM will really boost the transfert rate from I-RAM to disk? For me LVM was "just" a convenient way to see multiple volumes as a continuous source. I don't see how it will help here. Maybe because it will move large continuous chunk of data rather than multiple small "pages" that are in the swap.
I think I'll need to dig deeper for how Linux manage its swap partitions. Any recommended pointers?